# C# Image via Memorystream error (but only second time through)

Tags: arrays, image, gdi+

I need to be able to convert an Image to a byte Array and then back again. I've followed the google results and it seemed to be working..except it doesn't :)

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the Memory stream (I'm getting that GDI+ error) but I'm using the "using" and I thought I was cleanup up after myself.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image myImage = null;
        SetImage(ref myImage);  //This one works
        SetImage(ref myImage);  // This call breaks on 
                                //the first myImage.Save line
    }


    private void SetImage(ref System.Drawing.Image myImage)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] myImageAsBytes = null;

            //First time through we don't have an image already so we load from a file
            if (myImage == null)
            {
                myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\test.jpg");
            }


            //Convert our Image to a Byte Array.
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                myImage.Save(myMemoryStream, myImage.RawFormat);
                myImageAsBytes = myMemoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            //Just debugging
            myImage.Dispose();
            myImage = null;
            GC.Collect();


            //And convert it back to an image.
            //using (System.IO.MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myImageAsBytes))
            //{
            //    myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemoryStream);
            //}
           System.IO.MemoryStream myMemoryStream2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myImageAsBytes);
          myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemoryStream2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I think I may know what it is. I think it has something to do with that fact that the Image requires a "lifetime" memory stream. If I take the 2nd conversion (from Byte[] back to Image) out of the USING, an allow it to basically keep the memory stream.. it no longer errors out.

Comment: All... for anyone that comes along, yes that was the problem. When I convert the image from an array back to an image, you can not close\dispose the memory stream and must leave it in tact. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I know delphi but not C++. I think you have set myimage to null if myimage is an object, so tried to re-create. Or don't set it to null, just redraw on it or myimage.loadfromstream.

```
System.Drawing.Image myImage = null;
        SetImage(ref myImage);  //This one works
        myimage  :=create;
        SetImage(ref myImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Image.FromStream: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx

Says:

> You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image.

When it comes to MemoryStreams there is actually no point in closing/disposing them. It's the only .NET class I can think of that is IDisposable that doesn't need disposing. It accidentally inherits IDisposable from System.IO.Stream, that's why.

So I would recommend that you just create your memory streams and let them be.

If you were to use Image.FromStream on a physical file, however, maybe you wont like to keep it open. What you could do in that case is to make a copy of the bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap safeBitmap;
using ( var stream = blah-blah-blah )
using ( var img = Image.FromStream(stream) )
  safeBitmap = new Bitmap(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Its as simple as removing "ref" from everywhere***

I suggest you read up what that key word is doing, you will then understand why its breaking it.

**rather return the new image from the method.**

i.e. change it from void to return the new image.

**Update**

below is a console version of your code basically unmodified at ALL
and it runs fine.... although i don't agree with the programming at ALL either.
Point is where are you getting an error if it seems to run with no errors

```
class Program
{
    static  void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dosomething();
    }


    private static void Dosomething()
    {
        System.Drawing.Image myImage = null;
        SetImage(ref myImage);  //This one works
        SetImage(ref myImage);  // This call breaks on 
    }


    private static void SetImage(ref System.Drawing.Image myImage)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] myImageAsBytes = null;

            //First time through we don't have an image already so we load from a file
            if (myImage == null)
            {
                myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("C:\\temp\\test.jpg");
            }


            //Convert our Image to a Byte Array.
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                myImage.Save(myMemoryStream, myImage.RawFormat);
                myImageAsBytes = myMemoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            //Just debugging
            myImage.Dispose();
            myImage = null;
            GC.Collect();


            //And convert it back to an image.
            //using (System.IO.MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myImageAsBytes))
            //{
            //    myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemoryStream);
            //}
            System.IO.MemoryStream myMemoryStream2 = new System.IO.MemoryStream(myImageAsBytes);
            myImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemoryStream2);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but the ref has nothing to do with it. The same error will occur regardless. I just happened to use ref this go around to make the demo code easier to read.